# converting from a POP3 to IMAP on MS outlook2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, imap

I'm using MS Outlook 2013 and I want to convert my pop3 to IMAP without losing my rules and my emails.

I know how to create IMAP and how to export rules from pop3.
but i don't know how to keep my old mails in the new inbox and also save my new emails in the same old pst file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed the problem by myself as the following:

1. create IMAP account
2. delete pop3 account but leave the old data file as default (.pst)
3. click on the new profile then go to File->Manage rules and alerts->
   New Rule->from "start from a blank rule:"tab, choose "Apply rule on messages I receive"then press Next->Next->yes-> check on "move a copy to the specific folder" and choose "inbox" folder from the old profile(pop3) then press on "Finish".

To Do the same steps for sent messages:

1. Go to File->Manage rules and alerts->
2. New Rule->
3. from "start from a blank rule:"tab, choose "Apply rule on messages I
   sent"
4. then press Next->Next->yes-> check on "move a copy to the specific
   folder" and choose "sent items" folder from the old profile(pop3)
   then press on "Finish".